# Singular Homology of Real Projective Spaces

Tags: algebraic-topology

I'm following an induction argument to calculate the singular homology of $\mathbb{R}\mathbb{P}^n$ with coefficients in $\mathbb{Z}$. We decompose $\mathbb{R}\mathbb{P}^n$ into $U := \{[x_0 : \cdots : x_n] : x_0 \neq 0\}$ and $V = \mathbb{R}\mathbb{P}^n \setminus \{[1 :0 : \cdots : 0]\}$. Then up to homotopy equivalence we have $U \simeq \mathbb{D}^n$, $V \simeq \mathbb{R}\mathbb{P}^{n-1}$ and $U \cap V \simeq S^{n-1}$. We proceed by Mayer-Vietoris to calculate the homology, and for low degrees everything follows by exactness. The issue I'm running into is that when $n$ is even, in the top degrees, we get the sequence $$0 \to H_n(\mathbb{R}\mathbb{P}^n) \to \mathbb{Z} \xrightarrow{(i_*,j_*)} 0 \oplus \mathbb{Z} \to H_{n-1}(\mathbb{R}\mathbb{P}^n) \to 0$$
where $i : U \cap V \hookrightarrow{} U$ and $j : U \cap V \hookrightarrow V$. Exactness of the sequence isn't enough to figure out $H_n(\mathbb{R}\mathbb{P}^n)$ and $H_{n-1}(\mathbb{R}\mathbb{P}^n)$, so we need to determine what $j_*$ does. Looking at the argument for $\mathbb{R}\mathbb{P}^2$ and trying to generalize, I see intuitively why it must be that $j_* : 1 \mapsto 2$, but I don't see how to prove it formally.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at the maps more carefully.  The map $U\cap V\to V$ is $[1:x_1:x_2:\dots:x_n]\mapsto[x_1:x_2:\dots:x_n]$, so at the level of homology this is the same as the usual $S^{n-1}\to\mathbb{RP}^{n-1}=S^{n-1}/\pm 1$.  Consequently the generator $1=[S^{n-1}]$ is mapped to $1+(-1)^{n}$ times the $[\mathbb{RP}^{n-1}]$ (the $(-1)^n$ comes from the degree of the antipodal map).  Since $n$ is even, this is $1+(-1)^n=2$.

Comment: Thank you! Would you be able to explain more in depth how you know the map $H_{n-1}(S^{n-1}) \to H_{n-1}(\mathbb{R}\mathbb{P}^{n-1})$ is indeed given by $1 \mapsto 1 + (-1)^n$?

Comment: I'm just using the fact that, for a covering map $M\to M/\Gamma=N$, the map on top-dimensional homology is multiplication by the sum of (local) degrees of $\gamma\in\Gamma$.